# AWSLambdaException and InvalidSignatureException when running from Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, aws-lambda

I have a super simple mvn project which is running some code to get the tags of a Lambda function given the arn.

```
public static void listTag(String lambdaArn) {
        final AWSLambdaAsync lambdaClient = AWSLambdaAsyncClientBuilder.standard()
             .withRegion(Regions.EU_WEST_1)
             .build();
        final ListTagsRequest listTagsRequest = new ListTagsRequest();
        listTagsRequest.setResource(lambdaArn);
        final ListTagsResult listTagsResult = lambdaClient.listTags(listTagsRequest);
        final Map<String, String> tags = listTagsResult.getTags();
        ...
}
```

The code is working perfectly and I am able to get the tags.
If I call exactly the same code from a method inside a `@RestController` class in a Spring Boot application, it's not working anymore and I keep getting the following:

```
2019-05-23 10:16:51.075 ERROR 26045 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is com.amazonaws.services.lambda.model.AWSLambdaException: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details. (Service: AWSLambda; Status Code: 403; Error Code: InvalidSignatureException; Request ID: 7fb1ecf0-7d3b-11e9-89c2-8775f15f937d)] with root cause

com.amazonaws.services.lambda.model.AWSLambdaException: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details. (Service: AWSLambda; Status Code: 403; Error Code: InvalidSignatureException; Request ID: 7fb1ecf0-7d3b-11e9-89c2-8775f15f937d)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1712) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.534.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1367) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.534.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1113) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.534.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:770) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.534.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:744) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.534.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:726) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.534.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:686) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.534.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:668) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.534.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:532) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.534.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:512) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.534.jar:na]
```

I have tried of course to add my credentials when building the client, adding

```
.withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(new BasicAWSCredentials("accessKey", "secretKey")))
```

Both version of the library and Java are the same. Spring boot is version 2.1.3.RELEASE if this may help.

Answer (score 3):

I have same problem.
I solved directly add `httpclient` in `pom.xml` of my project.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
   <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
   <version>4.5.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Spring boot has dependency another version this library.
You need to add the module version required by `aws-java-sdk-core` library to `pom.xml`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this helped me after struggling for 2 days.